# How to prevent Chrome tabs or any kind of app from sleeping when in background?

Tags: applications, browser, youtube, background-process

I want to listen to things on Youtube (app) or on the web (Chrome) while doing other things on my Asus Transformer. Is there any way to prevent background Chrome tabs or background Apps from falling asleep?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's designed like that by the app's developers, so you can't.

Though for YouTube, if you're **rooted**, there is a [Xposed Module](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) called *Green YouTube* that have an option to play music from YouTube in background (but it doesn't work on my phone).

Comment: +1 that's about it. Green YouTube won't work for me in KitKat either. The only other way I've used is the split screen option on Samsung Devices which allows 2 apps running simultaneously, but obviously that won't apply to most devices. Google changed Youtube around 2.3 Gingerbread to not play when screen locked to stop people using it as a music player, and to push Google Music I'd wager. It cannot be a background task. They have never relented on this.

Comment: Shywim Are you a developer? Do you know of any ways to make the app believe it is in the foreground without rooting (A simple way to achieve what @RossC says about Samsung allowing 2 apps in the foreground, but without touching kernel code)?

Comment: I would imagine root access is a fundemental of overcoming this difficulty as Google have made it explicitly to work like this. Try Green Youtube in Xposed if you are rooted, otherwise you'd need to make BIG changes. You can't just port the split screen as the hardware may not be able to handle it and more importantly it is part of the Touchwiz framework and not Android itself sadly.

Comment: @Domi: Well there's some "floating apps" that enable you to have an apps on top of another. Search for `floating <name of your app> android` on Google, should return something, but there's no chrome and the last time I tried one for youtube, it didn't work (again).